# Chef resource notifications affecting notifying resource

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am relatively new to Chef and I'm trying to use the `:before` timer for  a few notifications for the first time. The idea is simple: I have a custom resource that pulls an artifact from a repository, saves it to a staging directory and then deploys it to the deployment directory. If the custom resource finds that the artifact must be deployed, the current deployment will be backed up to a backup directory and the new artifact will be deployed. If there's no need to deploy the artifact (due to the `not_if { some_condition }` line below), no backup steps will run (that's the whole point of using the notifications since the backup steps are only triggered via notifications).

In order to achieve this functionality, I created several resources with `action :nothing` and I am running them from my custom resource using notifications and the `:before` timer (see below). Every run I tried had `some_condition` evaluating to false.

```
# SNIPPET 1 - This is my intended code, whose behavior I can't understand. 
# All backup actions are set to :nothing and will be triggered
# only if some_condition is false.

directory "delete #{backup_dir}" do
  recursive true
  path backup_dir
  action :nothing
end

directory "create #{backup_dir}" do
  owner node['my_cookbook']['owner']
  group node['my_cookbook']['group']
  path backup_dir
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
  action :nothing
end

execute 'backup current deployment' do
  command "mv #{deployments_dir} #{backup_dir}"
  action :nothing
  only_if { ::Dir.exists?(deployments_dir) }
end

directory "create #{deployments_dir}" do
  path deployments_dir
  owner node['my_cookbook']['owner']
  group node['my_cookbook']['group']
  mode  "0755"
  recursive true
  action :nothing
end

node['my_cookbook']['artifacts'].each do |artifact_name|
  config = my_environment(artifact_name, node)
  # This custom resource downloads the artifact to a staging directory
  # and then moves it to deployments_dir.
  my_artifact_cache "my_cookbook::deploy_artifacts - Pull cached artifact #{artifact_name}" do
    snapshot      config['repository'] == 'snapshot'
    group_id      config['group_id']
    artifact_id   config['artifact_id']
    version       config['version']
    filetype      config['filename_extension']
    path          deployments_dir
    owner         node['my_cookbook']['owner']
    group         node['my_cookbook']['group']
    mode          "0755"
    action :pull
    not_if { some_condition }
    notifies :delete, "directory[delete #{backup_dir}]", :before
    notifies :create, "directory[create #{backup_dir}]", :before
    notifies :run, 'execute[backup current deployment]', :before
    notifies :create, "directory[create #{deployments_dir}]", :before
  end
end
```

However, every time I run the code above, some actions *within the `my_artifact_cache` custom resource* are skipped, and I have no idea why. This results in the run failing because the staging directory (which has nothing to do with the directories I'm actually manipulating via the notifications) is not created from within the custom resource. Without the notifications, the log shows `- created directory /staging/dir`, and with the notifications I get `- Would create new directory /staging/dir`.

When I run the second snippet below, everything works fine. I would expect that the two snippets would be equivalent in the case that `some_condition` is false. Why do the notifications seem to affect the behavior of the notifying resource? Am I missing something?

```
# SNIPPET 2 - Commented out the :nothing actions, replaced them with the actions
# from the notifications - this snippet works as expected. I expected
# snippet 1 to be equivalent during runtime if some_condition is false

directory "delete #{backup_dir}" do
  recursive true
  path backup_dir
  #action :nothing
  action :delete
end

directory "create #{backup_dir}" do
  owner node['my_cookbook']['owner']
  group node['my_cookbook']['group']
  path backup_dir
  mode '0755'
  recursive true
  #action :nothing
end

execute 'backup current deployment' do
  command "mv #{deployments_dir} #{backup_dir}"
  #action :nothing
  only_if { ::Dir.exists?(deployments_dir) }
end

directory "create #{deployments_dir}" do
  path deployments_dir
  owner node['my_cookbook']['owner']
  group node['my_cookbook']['group']
  mode  "0755"
  recursive true
  #action :nothing
end

node['my_cookbook']['artifacts'].each do |artifact_name|
  config = my_environment(artifact_name, node)
  # This custom resource downloads the artifact to a staging directory
  # and then moves it to deployments_dir.
  my_artifact_cache "my_cookbook::deploy_artifacts - Pull cached artifact #{artifact_name}" do
    snapshot      config['repository'] == 'snapshot'
    group_id      config['group_id']
    artifact_id   config['artifact_id']
    version       config['version']
    filetype      config['filename_extension']
    path          deployments_dir
    owner         node['my_cookbook']['owner']
    group         node['my_cookbook']['group']
    mode          "0755"
    action :pull
    not_if { some_condition }
    #notifies :delete, "directory[delete #{backup_dir}]", :before
    #notifies :create, "directory[create #{backup_dir}]", :before
    #notifies :run, 'execute[backup current deployment]', :before
    #notifies :create, "directory[create #{deployments_dir}]", :before
  end
end
```

Comment: :before notifications are probably the wrong way to go about this, but what is likely going on is that my_artifact_cache all the subresources inside it are not correctly written to be why-run safe and correctly report if they would be updated when run in why-run mode.  if you track down and fix all the why-run bugs, then the :before notification should work.

Comment: It would also likely be better to put the code to do the backups into the resource itself and it may be better to write it imperatively with a pure ruby FileUtils/File/Dir calls rather than using declarative chef resources.  The way that you're using a execute resource to fire an mv is some code smell here.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

chef resources run in the order they are written. that means that you can implement your logic in order.

seems to me that you are using [notifications](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#notifications) in order to achieve code reuse, but notification is not the way to go, since each chef resource must have unique name in order to avoid any resource collision or incorrect notifications, this is why [resource cloning has been deprecated](https://docs.chef.io/deprecations_resource_cloning.html).

if that is the case, there are better ways to achieve it in chef. such as, writing a [custom light weight resource provider (lwrp)](https://docs.chef.io/custom_resources.html) (also [read this](https://chef.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lwrps_custom.html)), or writing a [library](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html) (also [read this](https://blog.chef.io/2014/03/12/writing-libraries-in-chef-cookbooks/)).

Comment: I am not using notifications in order to achieve code reuse, but idempotence. All my resources have unique names.

Comment: Also, my idea is not to run the resources necessarily in the order they were written and that's why I am using the `:before` timer. Did you actually read my question?